# How can I define footnote before usage and reference it in macro?

Tags: footnotes

I learned how to do footnotes but I have some problem with solving using footnotes with macros `\newcommand`.

I want define footnote before usage and reference it later in `\newcommand` how can I do it? 
Is it possible?

My footnote will be repeated many times and I want to reduce amount of text to read.

```
\newcommand{\somemacro}[1]{
#1\footref{myfootnote}
}
}

\footnotetext{\label{myfootnote}Hello}
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to define a footnote once and then refer to it multiple times later on, but you cannot find a way so that the definition itself doesn't output the footnote marker. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this what you are looking for?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\myfncall}[1]{%
  \footnotemark[\ref{#1}]%
}

\begin{document}
See here.\myfncall{myfootnote}
This is one place where you use the foonote.\footnote{\label{myfootnote}%
  Text of the first footnote.}

Another footnote.\footnote{\label{otherfootnote}Text of the second footnote.}
Reference to the second footnote.\myfncall{otherfootnote}
Final reference\myfncall{otherfootnote} for good measure.

\clearpage
Beware: referencing a footnote\myfncall{myfootnote} from a different
page (page number~\pageref{myfootnote} here) this way may be confusing!
\end{document}
```

[image: Page 1]

---

Top of page 2:

[image: Top of page 2]

Comment: It is not what I want. Here footnote is already defined in text so can be easly referenced `This is one place where you use the foonote.\footnote{\label{myfootnote}% Text of the first footnote.}`. I want to refer footnote which is defined before but not marked in text before. It is because I want use macro to reference same footnote many times.

Comment: My command does avoid redundancy, sine each footnote text needs only be given once and the reference can be made as many times as one wants. I'm okay to allow you to define the footnote texts in a central place, but how is LaTeX going to know on which page you want them to be printed? That was precisely one of the goals achieved when using `\footnote` in my solution!

Comment: Thanks fo help this macro is good but not solve problem. I have idea for some workarounds but still have not idea how to solve it.

Comment: Workarounds for what? This answers the question. You didn't answer my previous comment in any meaningful way. How am I supposed to know what you want to do if you don't say it?

Comment: I want write for example such macro `\percentilefootnote` and use in whole section. Macro should always produce sentence with specific percentile description and refer to same footnote (do not confuse it with `\footnotemark[\ref{#1}]`). So first or last macro use should create probably footnote and rest should refer only to make less duplicates.

Comment: Difference of you solution with what is need is the you propose macro for referencing footnotes not for creating sentences with same foot note reference. You current macro lead to workaround solution but is not solution itself. My English is not perfect so I apologize for some mistakes.

Comment: You didn't say on which pages the footnote texts should be printed (i.e., how LaTeX is supposed to know where to print them). Comments here are not the place to describe the question. What you want to do is so unclear that I think I am going to give up, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for help I will try to ask question again in other form - maybe. Need rethink how to ask. I prefer to place footnote at the end of section or in last macro reference (bottom of section is the best not first occurrence).